# Fit text in to a shape using gd library

Tags: imagettftext

I am trying to put a text of any length (up to 15) in a shape like in below image using gd library. The width of shape should expand/reduce according to the text length. I know how to write simple text using gd library, but i am stuck on how to make this ?

[I am trying something similar like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpPVb.jpg)

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

$im = imagecreate(400, 300);

// Background color
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

// font color
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// text string
$text = 'ABCDEFG';

$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I tried creating text to image... now i want to fit that text in a shape... if the length of text increases the width of the shape has to be increased... and i m stuck on how to do this.

How can i achieve this ? any idea on this ?

Comment: You really need to show that you have put some efforts in searching google and finding some similar codes to start off, this is practically asking us to write the code for you, but unfortunately no one will do that for you since this is not a write-the-code-for-me-for-free-please community

Comment: I tried creating text to image... now i want to fit that text in a shape... if the length of text increases the width of the shape has to be increased... and i m stuck on how to do this.